# Nested SVG and offset with transform()

Tags: html, layout

I am generating a legend for a d3 graph.
Here is an excerpt of the resulting html.

```
<svg width="200" height="180" style="background-color: rgb(225, 210, 225);">
   <svg class="legend" id="#legendNodes"
        width="180" height="100">
        <g transform="translate(3,0)">
            <rect width="18" height="18" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></rect><text x="24" y="9" dy=".35em"
                style="font-size: 10px;">External...Artefact</text>
        </g>
        <g .../>
    </svg><svg class="legend" id="#legendLinks" width="180" height="80" transform="translate(0,120)">
        <g transform="translate(3,0)">
            <rect width="18" height="18" style="fill: rgb(214, 39, 40);"></rect><text x="24" y="9" dy=".35em"
                style="font-size: 10px;">External...Link</text>
        </g>
        <g ... />
    </svg>
</svg>
```

There are two shapes I'd like to put one above another: the list of nodes, and the list of links (well types).
I put them in a container and I "transform" the one below with the right offset (in this case 120px, l. 9).

This was working well on firefox, but now I need it on Chrome and it does not work anymore.

Any hint on how to fix this issue?

Thank you,
Edouard

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution: instead of tranform(), I've changed the y position.

`</svg><svg class="legend" id="#legendLinks" width="180" height="80" y="120">`